# updating table via SQL with variables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to update a table, via docmd.RunSql, and can't get it to update.

```
idlook = DLookup("[ID]", "119_review", "[todays_date] = #" & Format("" & Me.Combo87 & " " & Me.Combo89 & " 20" & Me.Combo91 & "", Medium) & "#")

MySQL = "UPDATE 119_review SET [Earned_Income]=" & Val(EarnedIncome) & " AND [Earned_income_withcal]=" & Val(EarnedIncomeCal) & " WHERE [ID]= " & idlook & ";"

Debug.Print MySQL
DoCmd.RunSQL MySQL
```

I've tried it both with and without brackets on the fields, the immediate window reads:

```
UPDATE 119_review SET Earned_Income=62 AND Earned_income_withcal=58.4 WHERE ID= 23;
UPDATE 119_review SET [Earned_Income]=62 AND [Earned_income_withcal]=58.4 WHERE [ID]= 23;
```

any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Any error messages? Are you sure there is a user with that ID? Are both these fields numeric? This all seems valid, so I can't replicate this update failing.

Comment: the ID I'm trying to update is "23" and it's inside the table. The data type of the two fields being updated are currency. No errors are displayed, it's like it reads the code and does nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a simple syntax error.

Different columns in an update statement should be separated by `,`, not by `AND`.
Weirdly enough, doing this wrong doesn't throw a syntax error, but just doesn't update anything.

Change the row setting your SQL string to the following:

```
MySQL = "UPDATE 119_review SET [Earned_Income]=" & Val(EarnedIncome) & " , [Earned_income_withcal]=" & Val(EarnedIncomeCal) & " WHERE [ID]= " & idlook & ";"
```

Comment: life saver! I've been caught up in website coding that I didn't even try that. Oddly enough, I thought about that just never tried it!